# Batch Inverting .PNG Images while maintaining transparency

Tags: batch, png, image-editing

I have a large number of monochrome PNGs that are black on transparent. I would like to invert them to be white on transparent. I've tried using XnConvert but it doesn't maintain the transparency.

Comment: since "transparency" is another word for "alpha channel" and alpha is a greyscale image, and your source is "black and white", you can try compositing a white image with the source image specified as the alpha mask. Imagemagik (command line) may be able to handle this via the -compose switch (?). GIMP is open source and allows for batch commands as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ImageMagick will do it:

for a single image:

```
convert black.png -negate white.png
```

for a directory full of images:

```
mogrify -negate *.png
```

The "-negate" option only affects the pixel color components and doesn't change the alpha (transparency).

Comment: Are you sure about that? I just ran the command and it has flipped the alpha and non-alpha channel. So rather than black-on-transparent, it's now transparent-on-white

Comment: I ran some tests and ImageMagick 6 works as I described, but ImageMagick 7 seems to be buggy.

Comment: Ahhh interesting! I wonder if it's a bug or intentional? Thanks for taking the time

Answer (score 4):

For ImageMagic7 you can disable the negation of the alpha channel like this:

```
mogrify -alpha deactivate -negate *.png
```

Comment: I had to use:
`magick convert *.png -alpha deactivate -negate -set filename:fname '%t-inv' '%[filename:fname].png'`